# Uber Api to keep checking taxis in local area

Tags: android, uber-api

I want to create an android app which can use the uber Api to constantly check the local area for an available taxi.

I thought of this idea because when I open uber it usually says no taxis available...I get one occasionally but I have to keep checking the app / leaving it open.

Is this possible using the uber Api? I couldn't find anything related!

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 1):

We don't expose an endpoint to communicate specifically where Uber is servicing which product. However, you can use [GET /v1/products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-products) to get that information. If you receive an empty response, no Uber products are available at the destination you specified. If you receive some products, you know that there are Uber products available. It sounds like you're just looking for Taxis, so you'd need to filter your products result to identify if that product category is serviced in your area.